# Modify spinnaker to listen on network IP, rather than localhost

Tags: tomcat, spinnaker

I'd like to expose deck on a network IP to share my setup with teammates.  It's listening on localhost right now (using aws quickstart), and I have to setup the appropriate tunneling in order to access it from my browser at http://localhost:9000.

I changed the Apache listen/virtualhost ports to 0.0.0.0:9000, and modified my spinnaker-local.yml to set the "services" host to 0.0.0.0.  For security reasons, I figured it would be better to keep the other microservices listening locally, and lock down deck with HTTP auth rather than deal with SAML or OAuth at this time.  But chrome is giving me what looks to be a CORS error when I access deck from the network ip:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8084/applications. The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.

I'm guessing this is originating from the access of Tomcat, but I'm not sure how to go about fixing it. Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a config in /opt/spinnaker/config/gate.yml

```
cors:
  allowedOriginsPattern: 'http://your ip address:9000'
```

then restart the gate `sudo restart gate`